# Acquire the data from a row in a Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, data-science

Instructions given by Professor:
1. Using the list of countries by continent from World Atlas data, load in the countries.csv file into a pandas DataFrame and name this data set as countries.
2. Using the data available on Gapminder, load in the Income per person (GDP/capita, PPP$ inflation-adjusted) as a pandas DataFrame and name this data set as income.
3. Transform the data set to have years as the rows and countries as the columns. Show the head of this data set when it is loaded.
4. Graphically display the distribution of income per person across all countries in the world for any given year (e.g. 2000). What kind of plot would be best?

In the code below, I have some of these tasks completed, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to acquire data from a DataFrame row.  I want to be able to acquire data from a row and then plot it. It may seem like a trivial concept, but I've been at it for a while and need assistance please.

```
%matplotlib inline 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
countries = pd.read_csv('2014_data/countries.csv')
countries.head(n=3)
income = pd.read_excel('indicator gapminder gdp_per_capita_ppp.xlsx')
income = income.T

def graph_per_year(year):
     stryear = str(year)
     dfList = income[stryear].tolist()
graph_per_year(1801)
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: Can you show us the output of `countries.head()` and `income.head()` for illustration?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas uses three types of indexing.

If you are looking to use integer indexing, you will need to use `.iloc`

```
df_1
Out[5]: 
          consId  fan-cnt
0  1155696024483     34.0
1  1155699007557     34.0
2  1155694005571     34.0
3  1155691016680     12.0
4  1155697016945     34.0

df_1.iloc[1,:] #go to the row with index 1 and select all the columns
Out[8]: 
consId     1.155699e+12
fan-cnt    3.400000e+01
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

And to go to a particular cell, you can use something along the following lines,

```
df_1.iloc[1][1]
Out[9]: 34.0
```

You need to go through the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for other types of indexing namely `.ix` and `.loc` as suggested by [sohier-dane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4893008/sohier-dane).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, a bar graph with a year sector would be best. You'll have to keep countries on y axis and per capita income on y. And a dropdown perhaps to select a particular year for which the graph will change.